# SQL Group up rows data into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, dense-rank

I have data in a table like this:

[image]

I want to organise the table data so that I can get a maximum of 3 letters per row grouped by account number.

Below would be the result I want:

[image]

I can use dense rank to group up the account numbers but not sure how to get the data I want in the format above.

[image]

Logic:
There are 4 letters for account 123. Final result groups by account number with first 3 letters as you can only have a maximum of 3 letters per row. The fourth letter must go on the second row.

Comment: Why D returned in the column Letter_A ?

Comment: Can you explain the logic here. It isn't obvious.

Comment: There are 4 lettersfor account 123. Final result groups by account number with first 3 letters as you can only have a maximum of 3 letters per row. The fourth letter must go on the second row.

Comment: Formatting data (e.g. wrapping results on multiple lines) is a task better suited for the front-end rather than SQL Server.

Comment: Use your DenseRank, then Row_Number() within that, and take the Module % of RowNum on 3 with Quotient as a sub modifier of Account_Group and the Remainder as column selector 0=Letter_A, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`, first creating a `row_number`, and then creating a row grouping using every 3 rows with `%` (modulus operator):

```
select account_number, 
       max(case when rn % 3 = 1 then letter end) as letter1,
       max(case when rn % 3 = 2 then letter end) as letter2,
       max(case when rn % 3 = 0 then letter end) as letter3
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by account_number, rn % 3 order by rn) newrn
    from (
       select *, row_number() over (partition by account_number order by letter) rn
        from yourtable 
        ) t
    ) y
group by account_number, newrn
order by account_number
```

- [Online Demo](http://rextester.com/KKLL89402)

Comment: Brilliant answer. I have used row number many times but never thought about using it in the from section to perform a double row number query.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with only one call to `row_number()`:

```
select account_number,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 1 then letter end) as letter_a,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 2 then letter end) as letter_b,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 0 then letter end) as letter_c
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by account_number order by letter) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by account_number, floor( (seqnum - 1) / 3)
order by account_number, min(seqnum);
```